# Maven command not producing TestNG reports to test-output/junitreports

Tags: java, maven, testng, testng-eclipse

Without configuring, I've been able to produce TestNG test results to the test-output/junitreports directory using Eclipse and running a TestNG run configuration.

However, when running my the same tests during my maven build (using the same test suite file), these test results are not produced.  How would I configure my maven test project to output the same way I see Eclipse+TestNG outputting the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to perform this output with the  configuration in my test project pom.xml

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        **<reportsDirectory>./test-output</reportsDirectory>**
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${testSuiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```